# Android webview url request with query string

Tags: android, url, webview, query-string

I need to know, in android sdk 4.0

the following line says that 'the file is not found'. But the webview loads perfectly in sdk 2.2 and 2.3 etc.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/currentLocation.html?width_="+grosswt+"&height_="+grossht);
```

Is there any other way to send query string with url in android webview?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug, even in ICS.

Google don't feel like fixing it.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a known bug with Android - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

Answer (score 2):

you have to do like this

```
String data = "<html><body><img src='your source url' width='1000' Height='1000'></body></html>";
                wbView.loadData(data, "text/html", null);
```

this solves my problem . I checked it in android 4.0,4.1,4.2 works great, hope it solves your problem .